# Django-admin: Add Dynamic row in admin like inline admin that is Not foreign key

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

i need to Add dynamically a field of model in Admin form, after that i need to dynamically add a part of my model.

my model is :

```
class CinemaShowTimes(models.Model):
   salon = models.ForeignKey(CinemaSalon)
   movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
   date = models.DateField()
   time = models.TimeField()
```

**for simplify importing data** of showtime in admin panel, at first i need **dynamically time**, and after adding multi time in form, i want to add new **dynamically row which has one date and multi time again**.

i need something like Foreign key Admin Inline for that, while i don't have any foreign key for those fields.

i don't know i should do it with javascript or directly Django Form or ModelForm provides this option for me.

is there any solution?